# WPF MVVM passing event parameters to view model

Tags: wpf, mvvm, event-handling, mouseevent, parameter-passing

I have grid control and I need to pass MouseWheel event to view model.

Now I'm doing this like that

```
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseWheel">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding MouseWheelCommand}"  />
        </i:EventTrigger>

    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

but I need to do different actions on mouse scroll up and mouse scroll down.
How to do that?

Can I do that without code in view and without extern libraries? Im using c#, wpf, visual studio 2010 express.

Answer (score 0):

For this you need MouseWheelEventArgs in your MVVM. So Pass this EventArgs as commandParamter. 
You can refer this link ---
[Passing EventArgs as CommandParameter](http://weblogs.asp.net/alexeyzakharov/archive/2010/03/24/silverlight-commands-hacks-passing-eventargs-as-commandparameter-to-delegatecommand-triggered-by-eventtrigger.aspx)

Then in your View-Model Class you can use this event args as follow

```
 void Scroll_MouseWheel(MouseWheelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Delta > 0)
        {
           // Mouse Wheel Up Action
        }
        else
        {
           // Mouse Wheel Down Action
        }

        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use input bindings with a custom mouse gesture, which is very easy to implement:

```
public class MouseWheelUp : MouseGesture
{
    public MouseWheelUp(): base(MouseAction.WheelClick)
    {
    }

    public MouseWheelUp(ModifierKeys modifiers) : base(MouseAction.WheelClick, modifiers)
    {
    }    

    public override bool Matches(object targetElement, InputEventArgs inputEventArgs)
    {
      if (!base.Matches(targetElement, inputEventArgs)) return false;
      if (!(inputEventArgs is MouseWheelEventArgs)) return false;
      var args = (MouseWheelEventArgs)inputEventArgs;
      return args.Delta > 0;       
    }
}
```

and then use it like this:

```
<TextBlock>
        <TextBlock.InputBindings>

            <MouseBinding Command="{Binding Command}">
                <MouseBinding.Gesture>
                    <me:MouseWheelUp />
                </MouseBinding.Gesture>
            </MouseBinding>

        </TextBlock.InputBindings>
        ABCEFG
 </TextBlock>
```